# Unable to receive mediaURL for pdf in twilio whatsapp python

Tags: python, flask, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to fetch the `mediaUrl` for the pdf that I am sending to `twilio` `whatsapp` number but it is not working. when i send images, it is picking up the `url` but with `pdf` files, `request.form.get('MediaUrl')` is None.

**form variable for Video:**

```
form variables ImmutableMultiDict([('MediaContentType0', 'video/mp4'), ('SmsMessageSid', 'MMae584ef25ecf72942fae05b1643470ef'), ('NumMedia', '1'), ('ProfileName', 'Person Name'), ('SmsSid', 'MMae584ef25ecf72942fae05b1643470ef'), ('WaId', '91XXXXXXXXXX'), ('SmsStatus', 'received'), ('Body', ''), ('To', 'whatsapp:+14155238886'), ('NumSegments', '1'), ('ReferralNumMedia', '0'), ('MessageSid', 'MMae584ef25ecf72942fae05b1643470ef'), ('AccountSid', 'AC8305baaf0505d8f8d43e4177ed278453'), ('From', 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXXX'), ('MediaUrl0', 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC8305baaf0505d8f8d43e4177ed278453/Messages/MMae584ef25ecf72942fae05b1643470ef/Media/MEfef42fe4e8e581706b5ae6cdddf5046c'), ('ApiVersion', '2010-04-01')])
```

**form variable for pdf**

```
form variables ImmutableMultiDict([('SmsMessageSid', 'SMea578b8027aaa3c0d75f953d80a71c6f'), ('NumMedia', '0'), ('ProfileName', 'Eshika Mahajan'), ('SmsSid', 'SMea578b8027aaa3c0d75f953d80a71c6f'), ('WaId', '91XXXXXXXXXX'), ('SmsStatus', 'received'), ('Body', ''), ('To', 'whatsapp:+14155238886'), ('NumSegments', '1'), ('ReferralNumMedia', '0'), ('MessageSid', 'SMea578b8027aaa3c0d75f953d80a71c6f'), ('AccountSid', 'AC8305baaf0505d8f8d43e4177ed278453'), ('From', 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXXX'), ('ApiVersion', '2010-04-01')])
```

My Code:

```
def reply():
    
    incoming_msg = request.form.get('Body')
    print(f"form variables {request.form}")
    personName=request.form.get('ProfileName')
    msg_from= request.form.get('From')
    message_received=f"hi {personName}, thanks for sending '{incoming_msg}'."
    mediaReceived=request.form.get("MediaUrl0")

    print("############ MEDIA received is")
    print(mediaReceived)
    print(message_received)
    resp=MessagingResponse()
    
    if request.form.get('MediaContentType0'):
        print(request.form.get('MediaContentType0'))
    else:
        print("found non")

    # mediaReceived="https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
    if mediaReceived:

        message_received=f"Thanks {personName},for sending image."
        Message2send=resp.message(message_received)
        Message2send.media(mediaReceived)
        url =mediaReceived
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        filename=msg_from+str(datetime.datetime.now())+str(".jpg")
        image=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

        open(image, 'wb').write(r.content)
        print(mediaReceived)
    if not mediaReceived:
        Message2send=resp.message(message_received)
    return str(resp)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaUrl` for PDF files is not available in the `request.form`. You can check for the existence of `MediaContentType0` in the form to identify if media is present and then handle the PDF differently.

Comment: Hi, as you can see in the form variables below, there is no MediaContentType0 for pdf files ImmutableMultiDict([('SmsMessageSid', 'SMea578b8027aaa3c0d75f953d80a71c6f'), ('NumMedia', '0'), ('ProfileName', 'Eshika Mahajan'), ('SmsSid', 'SMea578b8027aaa3c0d75f953d80a71c6f'), ('WaId', '91XXXXXXXXXX'), ('SmsStatus', 'received'), ('Body', ''), ('To', 'whatsapp:+14155238886'), ('NumSegments', '1'), ('ReferralNumMedia', '0'), ('MessageSid', 'SMea578b8027aaa3c0d75f953d80a71c6f'), ('AccountSid', 'AC8305baaf0505d8f8d43e4177ed278453'), ('From', 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXXX'), ('ApiVersion', '2010-04-01')])